# how to iterate values of perticular keys in python dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have something like this,

```
newlist = []

list =['a','b','c','d','e']

dict = {'a':['a','a1','a2','a3'],'b':['b','b1','b2','b3'],.....'e':['e','e1','e2','e3']
   }
```

I have tried like this,

```
for listval in list:
    newlist.append(dict[listval]].values())
```

But am not getting expected result,my expectation is,

```
newlist = [['a','a1','a2','a3'],['b','b1','b2','b3'],....,['e','e1','e2','e3']]
```

Comment: Don't call variables `list` and `dict` it's unimaginative and overwrites the builtins

Answer (score 1):

```
new_list = [the_dict[k] for k in the_list]
```

or if some keys might be missing:

```
new_list = [the_dict[k] for k in the_list if k in the_dict]
```

Comment: @1_CR: `live down Warner`? I've been away, sick for a couple of days. What did I miss?

Comment: @1_CR. I am a Kiwi. I just live here :p

Comment: @inspectorG4dget, I had to google it. It's a cricket reference I believe

Comment: @gnibbler: damn! I thought I missed an SO inside-joke ON THE ONE DAY I WAS TOO SICK TO BE ONLINE AS MUCH AS I USUALLY AM

Comment: LOL @inspectorG4dget, gnibbler, that's too much disclaiming for one night. See ya around.

Answer (score 1):

Try this - :

```
newlist = [dict.get(i) for i in list if dict.has_key(i)]
```

It will handle `key exists` and other errors.

Above will work for you.. :)

Comment: `.has_key` is deprecated for _ages_. Just use `i in dict` and choose a less confusing name for `dict`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` if you know for sure that all the keys will be in the list.

```
list1 =['a','b','c','d','e']
dict1 = {'a':['a','a1','a2','a3'],'b':['b','b1','b2','b3'],'c':['c','c1','c2','c3'],'d':['d','d1','d2','d3'],'e':['e','e1','e2','e3']}
newlist = map(dict1.get, list1)
```

Comment: That gives `None` for missing keys. If you prefer an exception, use `dict1.__getitem__`